# calling c++ hidden operator function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to ask how to call hidden Base class operator function in derived class overriding function, below is my code, the comment line is the question.

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual bool operator^(Base &b){
        cout << "hehe" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    virtual void fn() = 0;
};

class Dev: public Base{
public:
    virtual bool operator^(Base &b){
        // how to call operator ^ in the Base class here??
        cout << "haha" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    virtual void fn(){}
};
```

Comment: I suppose you want to take a `Dev& d` in the derived operator?

Comment: `Base::operator^(b)`  not sure how to put this into a full fledged answer though

Comment: I suppose explain the reason it's like that. Explain the scope `::` and why it's needed? And also suggest he puts `override` at the end of the overridden virtual for clarity and good practice. @UKMonkey

Comment: I think I'd rather focus on that it's not "hidden" but "overridden".  Hidden has another meaning that tends to result in pain when encountered.  But I leave that as a task for OP to research.

Answer (score 3):

Use a qualified name of the operator.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    virtual bool operator^(Base &b){
        cout << "hehe" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    virtual void fn() = 0;
};

class Dev: public Base{
public:
    virtual bool operator^(Base &b){
        Base::operator^( b );
        cout << "haha" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    virtual void fn(){}
};

int main() 
{
    Dev v;
    Base &b = v;

    v ^ b;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hehe
haha
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do an explicit upcast of `*this`:

```
class Dev: public Base{
public:
    virtual bool operator^(Base &b)
    {
        static_cast<Base&>(*this) ^ b;

        cout << "haha" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    virtual void fn(){}
};
```